# Out Of Bounds Puzzle [Level !]

Tags: keys-and-locks

Unlock the lock with the key.

> You might want to put this next to a certain website's url. It was a gift to another website, if you've read it before.
>
> /a/8QemVeM

Is enough said already?

> Complete the link.
>
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hClK7Sn

Something to do with this square of characters.

> x ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎d ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎ -
>
> h  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎A  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎ v
>
> U  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎7  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎ o
>
> > Complete this next link using the square of characters provided.
> >
> > https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pS

You must unlock the lock with the key. What kind of lock is it?

p.s. you might need to use this for a later puzzle. . .
ZZa7WAc

Comment: Level !? Do you mean level 1 or not?

Comment: Yes, I mean level 1. There are four more levels after this one, each being more difficult as the one before it.

Comment: I added /a/8QemVeM to the end of the first link and it said video unavailable, which fits the title, out of bounds puzzle.

Comment: I grouped together some of the sentences so it makes more sense.

Comment: Hm, I think I made this one a bit too easy. . . I guess I'll just have to make the second puzzle much more difficult.

Comment: Puzzles really should be self-contained.  See: https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6299/internet-wide-puzzles

Comment: I wouldn't say it's too easy, but as someone who's involved with args, I recognize the formats of the things you have linked easily.  This is the "many-eyes" concept.  Get enough people to look at something and someone knows it.

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it.  If not, a response to the answerer that helps steer them in the right direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Partial Answer:

Step 1: Go to...

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruWAI.jpg
>  Reuploaded here:
>  [image]

Step 2:

> PFP is here: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/52488/enqrypted-deviniled
>  Reuploaded here:
>  [image]

Step 3:

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hClK7SnjjOQ
>  This comment is left on the video
>  [image]

Comment: Oh, the link is correct alright. The video has no correlation, though.